# Disadvantages of building own components (such as SR latch)?

Tags: components, component-selection

So I browsed Digikey for way too long today looking for an SR latch.  I wanted something low power that would use very low quiescent current for a varied range of VCC and work for between 2-5 volts VCC. After a while I realized that I could just wire two NOR gates together and get exactly what I needed.  Thinking back on it, for some reason I almost never take this route and I wasn't sure why.

SO my question for you is, in general is there a reason to use prepackaged parts when available to avoid building from scratch? As opposed to building from more fundamental parts like resistors, capacitors, AND/OR gates, etc.

Comment: I did understand your question, then I came the "as opposed to" part and then I thought maybe I don't understand the question. What parts are you excluding from potential answers? It's been a long day.

Comment: @Andyaka   None really.. Its more using fundamental parts and design VS reading datasheets until you find someone who has already built something with the same functionality

Answer (score 5):

Really, the biggest reason is convenience. Lots and lots of components exist just for convenience. Why use a supervisor or reset monitor instead of a reference and a low voltage comparator with some hysteresis? Because reset monitors come in sot-23 packages. Simple as that. Hell, why do resistor arrays exist? No other reason than convenience (except for matched arrays, but that's a different story).

For prototyping and generally small series I'd recommend just using those convenience items. It produces cleaner schematics and makes your life a lot easier. Once you get into big production you can start looking into these kinds of things: thinking outside the box to save a couple pennies, consolidating parts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of issues, and what is important to you (or for this board) is not always valid for the next board.  Here are some issues, in random order.

**Advantages for prepackaged parts:**

Convenience.  It is a whole lot easier getting exactly the part you want already made.

Speed:  Prepackaged parts are often much faster than the equivalent circuit that you make yourself.

Power:  Prepackaged parts are often lower power (but not always!).

Size:  Prepackaged parts are often smaller.

**Advantages for making your own:**

Customization:  Many prepackaged parts are going away, or not available with newer technologies.  In many cases, only the more simple parts are available.  You can make the more complex or "odd" parts yourself.

What you have:  You might already have some unused gates on your board that you can use.  Rather than put yet another IC on your PCB, you can use some of the unused gates that are already there.

Cost:  Similar to "what you have", in that using what is already there or easily available can sometimes save you money.